# Is there a way to programmatically get the NOTIFY payload size limit?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out the size limit of the NOTIFY payload in PostgreSQL, in order to split my messages into smaller packages.

This has to be done programmatically, as my script is intended to run on other people's servers.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I looked around in the documentation and on the web and didn't find anything.

Comment: That's the wrong approach I think. Don't send large message payloads through NOTIFY. It's a lot better to e.g. just send the PK of the modified rows as the payload.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why do you think that? I need to send the diff itself (which is a heavy calculation to do) through NOTIFY, so that the other clients will not need to do the same calculation. Do you still see this as the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough rep to answer in the comment section so, I will give the reason for the answer of @a_horse_with_no_name.
In the offical docs, they state that you should handle it like he/she described:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-notify.html

`The “payload” string to be communicated along with the notification. This must be specified as a simple string literal. In the default configuration it must be shorter than 8000 bytes. (If binary data or large amounts of information need to be communicated, it's best to put it in a database table and send the key of the record.)`

You can find it under "Parameters" of payload